# how to access single activity button from different ViewPager Fragment?which tab is currently selected

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to submit fragment data on **Done** button click. **Done** button in toolbar so I am able to directly access from fragment and I have used

```
usertextView_done = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_tv_icon_done);
```

But using this method only one instance created and it called from all tab.
Thanks in Advance Here I have my screen

[image: Done is Button in toolbar and have 5 tab]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that. You could have an error.

In my opinion the correct way would be (from the Activity) to access the current Fragment and call a public method (for example `onActivityButtonPressed()`).